# How to debug Gitlab CI scheduled pipeline not running?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab CI pipeline schedule and noticed that pipelines are not running (anymore).

When starting the schedule manually via the UI (`<repo-root>/-/pipeline_schedules`) it shows the following

[image]

However, there is no pipeline started and no error message is provided.

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The success message is misleading in the sense that one might thing the pipeline was actually created, although it only means that a pipeline was scheduled.

There are various reasons, why a schedule cannot run (anymore).
This can be for example because of conflicting rules or outdated fields in your yml caused by breaking changes due to Gitlab upgrades.

---

To get to the root of the problem why your pipeline did not run you can **trigger a pipeline manually** and set the
`CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` to hold `"schedule"` as value.

To do so, go to `<repo-root>/-/pipelines/new`, set your target branch or tag and the variable as follows

[image]

---

Additionally, you may want to provide further variables required to properly simulate your problematic schedule via the manual run.

---

Next hit `Run pipeline` and you should observe an actual error message why the pipeline could not run.

[image]